# How to find which view is causing 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints'

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

Sometimes I will get a layout issue, but I won't be sure which view is sending it. First I get logs like this

```
2020-07-17 18:46:00.243783+0200 your-app[97175:3182603] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a76d00 UIView:0x7f967ff233d0.width == - 16   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a76d00 UIView:0x7f967ff233d0.width == - 16   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

How do I tell which view is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Wait for error to log**

Do whatever thing causes the error to log, when it does look at the info that looks like this:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a76d00 UIView:0x7f967ff233d0.width == - 16   (active)>
```

From here, note the memory address of the view, in this case `0x7f967ff233d0`

**Step 2: Pause App**

In xcode, above the console, click on the pause button so the app stops and we can enter lldb commands

**Step 3: Interact with memory address**

Now that we have the memory address, we can run things against it, for example:

log object:

```
expr -l objc -O -- 0x7f967ff233d0
```

log property:

```
expr -l objc -O -- [0x7f967ff233d0 someProperty]
```

**Change Background Color Live**

And the way I was able to find mine, you can execute code against this object live, using this, we can set the background color to something obvious and visually identify.

```
expr -l objc -O -- [0x7f967ff233d0 setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]]
```

from there, just click play and find the problem view visually.